# How to ask the date to a server from windows terminal?

Tags: windows, date

For example, if I want to know if I am connected I can use:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

to send a ping to google DNS server. Can I ask in a similar way the date of a server? Something like:

```
give_me_your_date 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: ping doesn't check if you are connected. And this would be a huge security problem if it was possible. What other info would you be able to get from a ping?

Comment: and there is some specific server designed exclusively to just response with its local date? I just need to check if the locale date is equal to a remote date from any existing server

Comment: @JacobH it's not really a security problem, NTP servers are routinely set up without particular issues. The only problem is, as usual, server load (which is generally not significant for time servers) and increased network traffic if you publish it into the "official" NTP pool. And, well, increased attack surface, but that's true for any service.

Answer (score 1):

if you had curl you could

```html
curl -I http://example.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 16 Oct 2016 23:37:15 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.24
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

and you if that server is a webserver you would get an http header which you can retrieve the date from

you can get curl for windows here https://curl.haxx.se/download.html